# Scraping multiple job listing sites for extracting job description, location etc

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I have a text file containing list of job searching websites like [indeed.com](http://www.indeed.com), [careerbuilder.com](http://www.careerbuilder.com) etc.
I need to scrape each and every site that is listed in the text file to find the Jobs for given keywords using **Python**.
The problem here is, every site have their own layouts. I need to scrape them with same program **instead of writing a separate code for each and every site that is listed**.
Can someone help me with this??

Comment: Your question is broad. Can you be more specific? Pick a couple of websites. Show us your code you tried. Where you got stuck. What you want as the result. See also [mcve].

Comment: I would be happy to help you do your job. How much will you pay me? Yes, my comment is snarky. But that's because your question obviously is not a generic "I don't understand how to do X using Python". Too, that you are using Python is completely irrelevant to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scraping requires some searching parameters. When I used to scrape websites, I used a search between function and found the unique html wrappers used for different things on the website (name, number, address) etc. They may have been stored as:

```
<div class="userName" id="userName">This is a username</div>
```

So I would use a function to search for this first part of the html, and end it with a search for the ending div and return the contents in between.

However its unlikely that the different websites have the same html structure. So you would have to write rules for each different website you needed to scrape.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the reason there are no official softwares for webscraping is for this same reason as far as i know. you have to study page layout and write the suitable program for it. There's no one solution fits all in web scraping. even being a badass in regex won't help much. i've been through similar situation before

Comment: how about training a ML model? Is that even possible?

Comment: Possible? pretty sure. But i doubt you'd wanna go through that hurdle. How would you get training data? by analyzing most if not all the websites on your list. That brings you very close to what you're running from